# link and label inside li tag does not work in IE 11

Tags: hyperlink, label, html-lists

Hi I have a link like this..

```
<li><a href="page.html"><label class="mobile">next page</label></a></li>
```

This link work in all browsers except Internet Explorer... It only works if I remove the label part, anyone knows why and how I can work around it?

Comment: Hi, having the same issue now. Had you fixed it?